# How to disable the bootstrap form validation?

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I'm trying to use the default input email validation (as attached in the snippet). However, the website I'm developing is using bootstrap. It seems like bootstrap uses its own validation concept.
As soon as I start typing in a bootstrap input field, it already shows an error:
[image: bootstrap email validation uses .has-error as soon as you start typing]

While the default input type email validation allows you to type before judging whether your input is valid. (Which is exactly what I would like to achieve)

So is it possible to disable the bootstrap form validation and use the default one instead?

```html
<form>
  Mail:
  <input type="email" name="email">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: There is no form validation in Bootstrap.

Comment: Hm.. this explains why I can't find any validation code via bootstrap files.
But still: why does the form input act differently?

Comment: look for jqueryvalidation

Comment: use full link 

http://formvalidation.io/examples/skip-validation-specific-submit-button/

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why the bootstrap inputs behave differently than non-bootstrap-styled inputs (thanks to makshh for pointing out that bootstrap really does not use form validation!)

bootstrap:
`input:invalid` class is styled without considering the focus

no bootstrap:
`input:invalid` class is styled, but not applied once the focus has been removed once